# Possible to use javascript var in Razor?

Tags: jquery, razor, kendo-ui

I have a Kendo scheduler, where I have to set the height to the size of the screen
And the kendo scheduler height only allow integer:

```
...
.Height(600).
....
```

And I know can get the height of the screen via jQuery:

```
var height = $( window ).height();
```

But Is there a way to use this javascript variable?

Answer (score 1):

Not using the C#/Razor API no, as that code is already rendered by the time any client-side code could execute, but you could initialise it using the Javascript API:

```
<div id="scheduler"></div>
<script>
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
  date: new Date("2013/6/6"),
  height: $( window ).height(),
  dataSource: [
    {
      id: 1,
      start: new Date("2013/6/6 08:00 AM"),
      end: new Date("2013/6/6 09:00 AM"),
      title: "Interview"
    }
  ]
});
</script>
```

http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/scheduler#configuration-height